# Laravel: Adding custom attribute to validation of array of files not working

Tags: laravel, validation, file-upload, attributes

I am unable to change the attribute for the array of files in Laravel Validation.

in my `FormRequest` class, I've made the following validation

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'product_images' => 'nullable|array',
        'product_images.*' => [nullable, File::image()],
    ];
}

public function attributes() {
    return [
        'product_images.*' => 'Showcase images'
    ];
}
```

But in validation errors, it still shows as `product images.0 must be an image` & not as `Showcase images must be an image` which should be the expected output.

PS: This is happening only in case of file validations and working fine in normal validations

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom validation message to the lang/validation.php. You can put it at the designated array for custom validation message at the  very bottom of the file.

example :

```
'product_images.*' => [
    'image' => 'Show case image must be an image',
]
```

also insead of `File::image()` change it to `image` because I don't if it will work if you dont chamge it.

Comment: The custom message validation worked. But it's a workaround, not a solution. My problem is that it should take the custom attribute. For now, I have to rewrite every single validation for my array of files in custom validation.

N yes, `File::image()` works. :) I have some dynamic values to be added, So, I have to use the validator classes instead of literals.